# Is Director Vance actually another person?

Tags: character, ncis

In the 6<sup>th</sup> season of NCIS, we come across an episode (*Knockout*), where Tyler Owens, a boxer and a friend of Director Vance, is found dead. Vance starts leading the investigation, and Gibbs become more and more suspicious as he finds out:

- that the deceased, a supposed former Marine, doesn't have a military record, yet Vance says he was a Marine;
- that Vance told his wife he was discharged from the USMC because of a detached retina, and the deceased had a detached retina.

We then find out that Vance was involved in a black op (Operation Frankestein), which he basically invented just after getting out of the Naval War College.

Gibbs has a file on Vance from the CIA, but never opens it. However, he seems to hint at other characters that the Director may be another person.

The question is: is Vance actually Owens? If so, is the replacement Owens/Vance somehow related to Operation Frankestein and possibly other black ops?

Comment: We... never find out. They seem to have dropped the plot thread. I think Gibbs pulls the file from its hiding place in his basement once, but never used it. All the way up to season 11 anyway.

Comment: @cde Feel free to expand your comment into an answer!

Comment: I'm not 100% on this. Been a while since I've seen the relevent episodes